# How to enable mysqli on XAMPP?

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

By seeing suggestions throughout the Internet I tried to convert all my queries to mysqli.

But mysqli is not working in my XAMPP. I checked my PHP folder and there is a `php_mysqli.dll` file... still it doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you declare it to php.ini to load it? If no, try find this in php.ini and add php_mysqli.dll

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

extension= php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: Restart your xampp once you have applied the settings.

Comment: I've double checked and it's ok: `extension=php_mysqli.dll` and I've tried your suggestion in my case: `extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"` and I've restarted Apache service but still no luck!
I've verified it's this php.ini file which `PHPMyAdmin` uses, but I still got the message `"You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable of handling multi queries. <b>The execution of some stored routines may fail!</b> Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any problems."`Any other suggestions??

Comment: Thanks. I'm using XAMPP v3.0.12, I've just downloaded a few days ago. I don't have enough time to install all the components individually, I know it's better, but for now I'll use this all-in-one package. hank you =)

Answer (score 4):

Goto the directory `phpMyAdmin`, find there is a file with name `config.inc.php`, open the file and find a line there as:
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql'`;
just change `mysql` to `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that might be blocking the msqli dll from loading could be user right issues on your local webserver, make sure the \User can read the ext folder, that was what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use XAMPP 1.8.3-1, XAMPP 1.8.2-2, XAMPP 1.8.1.
Because these xampp versions also support Mysqli by default.