# Blank page when trying to run my php code to connect to my phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database on phpmyadmin with a table that contains some information. I am trying to check the connection to it by writing this code:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

but it just shows me a blank page when I'm running it in browser. I named it conn.php and I'm running it with localhost/conn.php, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: variables are assigned where/how? didn't choose a database... so when in doubt... check for errors ;-)

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the code? I mean, before the connection

Comment: yes please provide full code otherwise this function runs correct i checked in my local environment also.

Comment: Pages is returning as a 500, 200, other? `phpmyadmin` isn't a dbms.

Comment: <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "myusername";
    $password = "mypassword";
    
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password) or     die("Can't connect");
    
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>

Comment: I checked this code on another database, having no username or password, and it worked. It showed the "connected successufully" message. This one doesn't. And I am sure I am writing the right username and password

Answer (score 0):

Check logs in /var/log/apache/error.log to see what is wrong.

Have you enabled mysqli module? It can be a reason.

Comment: If I started mysql from xampp? I don't know how to check logs. I found an error.txt in apache/logs, but I understand nothing from there :D

Comment: Post the last related records and see what is wrong.

Comment: [Thu May 19 16:18:05.980928 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3764:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu May 19 16:18:06.212718 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3764:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu May 19 16:18:06.297365 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3764:tid 556] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: [Thu May 19 16:18:04.947433 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Thu May 19 16:18:04.947433 2016] [core:notice] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu May 19 16:18:04.947433 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3764

Comment: [Thu May 19 16:18:04.577969 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu May 19 16:18:04.729868 2016] [core:warn] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu May 19 16:18:04.862292 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 5072:tid 552] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Logs contains 'fatal error' is valuable. Try add file phpinfo(), <?php phpinfo() ?> and then visit it, check if there is a mysqli menu. If not, try to enable mysqli module. To enable this module see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170400/mysqli-not-working-in-xampp-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to check for all errors you encounter. This might also give information about why you see empty page. Good luck.

Comment: I added that code to mine. still blank page when running

Comment: Yea... then only /logs/error.log (or whatever link it is) will help. In there you should find an answer.