# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() persistent issue

Tags: php, mysqli

This code is throwing the following error:*Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()*. I have already made sure extension=php_mysqli.dll is uncommented but still the error persists. I am using Php version 5.6 and the code below is from the Udemy course so I don't think it's wrong. Any ideas how to fix this please? Also, I've tried this code on 2 different Pcs with wamp and xampp. I thought I would also mention I'm using Phpstorm as my IDE

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename = "tutorial";


$dbconnected = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

$dbselected = mysqli_select_db($databasename, $dbconnected);

if($dbconnected) {
    echo "Mysql connection success";
    if ($dbselected) {
        echo "DB connection success";
    } else {
        echo "DB connection failure";
    }
}else {
        echo "Mysql connection failure";
}
```

Comment: Try running a `phpinfo();` (`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`) and see if the mysqli extension is loaded.

Comment: I assume you restarted the webserver after uncommenting?

Comment: Yes mysqli extension is loaded

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your system is Window-based. This command helped me to know which PHP modules installed.

```
[centos@localhost sites]$ php -m | grep mysql
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

I'm going out on a limb and assume your PHP extension directory is missing a php_mysqli.dll file necessary to fix the undefined function because the function simply do not exist.

For window-based system, please try the following command:

```
php -m
```

And list only the modules that contain "mysql" in the resultset.

Could you let us know whether your system is missing mysqli from modules or php_mysqli.dll from extension directory?

Comment: Just checked and the file php_mysqli.dll is not missing :(

Comment: My apologizes. In this case, you are using WAMP or XAMPP binaries. What is the path to PHP extension directory and is php_mysqli.dll uncommented in WAMPP/XAMPP's php.ini configuration file?

Comment: Yes it's uncommented

Comment: I'm not quite sure where the problem is but after looking into other stackoverflow questions, you might want to download all-in-one package as explained in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12170432/5012277).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that while using Phpstorm I had downloaded a version of Php without a php.ini file....