# Missing of mysqli extension in xampp phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, localhost

i changed my php version on local server.. After change the php version when i opened localhost/phpmyadmin then this error occurs and i cant go to the phpmyadmin screen.

"The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration".

Comment: Have you tried enabling it in your new php.ini?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170400/how-to-enable-mysqli-on-xampp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable mysqli on XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170400/how-to-enable-mysqli-on-xampp)